# making a css triangle float on an image during transitions

Tags: css

So, I want a colored triangle floating on the edge of a picture.
On hover the picture zooms and a filter is applied.

I have 3 issues and one which are:

1. I haven't got the triangle floating vertically in the middle of the
   picture and stuck to the left hand side.
2. When it's in mobile mode
   as a column, the triangle should change to center horizontally
   and at the bottom, I've not managed this.
3. I'd like the triangle to
   remain visible on top of the picture.  But if I set the z index this
   isn't working, it appears to be behind the image and disappears on
   hover.
4. I'd really like to make both the image transition, and it's
   adjacent text box on hover, of either div.  But with different
   effects.  The text box getting a darker background and the image
   becoming brighter.  Is there a way of making that happen with
   javascript?  How would I do it?

```css
div.link-text {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 24px;
  width: wrap;
  display: flex;
  border: solid pink 1px;
  /*background-color: pink;*/
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  order: unset;
  transition: all 2s ease;
} 

div.link-text : nth-child(1) { order: 2; }
div.link-text : nth-child(2) { order: 1; } 


.article-container {
  width: 540px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: top;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0em;


  transition: all 2s ease;       
  /* fade in */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /*< 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s; /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}


.article-container>div {flex: 0 auto; }
.article-container :nth-child(1) { order: 2; }
.article-container :nth-child(2) { order: 1; }



div.article-pane {
  align-self: flex-start;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 540px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  height: 405px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

.article-container:hover { background-color: darkgreen; }

/* needed to keep the article title on top of the text on mobile */
div.article-pane :nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
div.article-pane :nth-child(2) { order: 2; }

img.responsive {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 2s ease;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

img.responsive:hover {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

.arrow-right {
  position: relative;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
}

@media screen and (min-width:1080px){
  .article-container{
    flex-direction: row; 
    width:1080px;
    padding-left:0;
    padding-right:0;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items:center;
    margin:auto;
  }
  
  .article-container>div { flex: 1; }
  .article-container :nth-child(1) { order: 1; }
  .article-container :nth-child(2) { order: 2; }   
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article-pane">
    <div class="link-text">
      <a href="blog/fettes-college-edinburgh-castle-teviot.html" class="title">A look at Edinburgh's 'Harry Potter castles'</a>
      
      <span>
        Don't be cheated by Harry Potter guides, counter the unplottable 
        charm & watch the Gothic majesty of the finest school of witchcraft & wizardry 
        materialise
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="article-pane" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">
    <picture>
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/10/03/21/13/shock-headed-boletus-3722395_960_720.jpg" class="responsive" 
    alt="Gothic Fettes college is rich with similarities to Harry Potter's Hogwarts"/>    
    </picture>

    <div class="arrow-right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might want to start with fixing your html markup

Comment: OK think I've done that.  I've got it so hovering on th eimage darkens the background of the entire 'article-container', conversely though when I hover on the article-pane I'd like the image to transition, I don't think that's possible, pfft.  Anyway would love help with getting triangle to show and float atop the picture irregardless of picture hover transitions.

Answer (score 0):

Your first 3 issues can be solved by absolute positioning the arrow.

```css
div.link-text {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 24px;
  width: wrap;
  display: flex;
  border: solid pink 1px;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  order: unset;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

div.link-text: nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}

div.link-text: nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

.article-container {
  width: 540px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: top;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0em;
  transition: all 2s ease;
  /* fade in */
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  /*< 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 2s;
}

.article-container>div {
  flex: 0 auto;
}

.article-container :nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}

.article-container :nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

div.article-pane {
  align-self: flex-start;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 540px;
  border: solid black 2px;
  height: 405px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}


/* needed to keep the article title on top of the text on mobile */

div.article-pane :nth-child(1) {
  order: 1;
}

div.article-pane :nth-child(2) {
  order: 2;
}

img.responsive {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 2s ease;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.arrow-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
  border-left: 20px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

@media screen and (min-width:1080px) {
  .article-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 1080px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    margin: auto;
  }
  .article-container>div {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .article-container :nth-child(1) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .article-container :nth-child(2) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .arrow-right {
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    left: 10px;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
}

.article-container:hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.article-container:hover img.responsive {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
  filter: grayscale(0%);
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="article-container">
  <div class="article-pane">
    <div class="link-text">
      <a href="blog/fettes-college-edinburgh-castle-teviot.html" class="title">A look at Edinburgh's 'Harry Potter castles'</a>
      <span>Don't be cheated by Harry Potter guides, counter the unplottable 
  charm & watch the Gothic majesty of the finest school of witchcraft & wizardry 
  materialise</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="article-pane" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">

    <picture>
      <source srcset=" https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
      <!-- ios media -->
      <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature/grayscale " class="responsive " alt="Gothic Fettes college is rich with similarities to Harry Potters Hogwarts " />
    </picture>

    <div class="arrow-right "></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Let me know still need help solving this.